# PHP 7.2.5 Loading extensions

Tags: php

I am trying to add [ast extension](https://github.com/nikic/php-ast) . I downloaded the files and added **php_ast.dll** to my PHP/ext folder, which is located in path: **C:\PHP7\ext** . 
After that I enabled the extension in php.ini file and restared powershell. If I run **php -m** command, I get a following warning.

> PHP Warning: PHP startup: Unable to load ynamic library 'ast' (tried: C:\PHP7\ext\ast (The specified module could not be found.), C:\PHP7\ext\php_ast.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) In uknown on line 0.

I tried to copy the second path (C:\PHP7\ext\php_ast.dll) to file explorer and It opens the file, so I don't understand why the module could not be found.

Comment: Which one of the possible dll's did you download?

Comment: Windows: Download a prebuilt Windows DLL and move it into the ext/ directory of your PHP instalation. ---> Furthermore add extension=php_ast.dll to your php.ini file.
Do you have done that? https://github.com/nikic/php-ast#installation

Comment: For windows you will need the `php_ast-0.1.6-7.2-ts-vc15-x86.zip` or the `php_ast-0.1.6-7.2-ts-vc15-x64.zip` which one depends upon wether you have a 32bit or 64bit version of PHP. The NTS (Not Thread Safe) versions wont run on windows

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is the correct question, I downloaded the last one, well It turns out that I have nts version of PHP and the extension was for ts version. I downloaded the right version of ext and It is working! Thanks

Comment: Oh, OK thats interesting

Comment: I assume you have just PHP and are not using Apache as well :)

Comment: Yes that true, I just wanted to install php phan to my project which uses php 5.6  so I can analyze what will I need for migration to php 7. So I just used composer with php 7